# C# creating multilingual application with plugin support (MEF)

Tags: c#, plugins, mef, multilingual

I have read many articles and questions here on SO about this, however I am still not comfortable. I am planning to develop a plug-in based GUI desktop application based on MEF technology.

I would like to provide a localization support for the application. The problem is that even if I localize the host application, the third party plugins which are basically DLL files and can be installed any time, will also need to be localized.

I think having all localizable controls in a dll is not an option for me. I can store the international texts in a database, have a caller function which is retrieving the text from DB in the host applciation, and ask plugins to call this caller function. Or I can ask the developers to have different resource files in their applications, but this way, they will not benefit from already translated texts.

What is the best practise to provide multilingual interface for this case?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Can you please expand on the problem you are having with third party localization plugins with MEF? and which plugins are you using?

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is one best practice that applies, but I can talk you through the options as I see them.  If you develop a central database with your different translations for everything, all of your tools can benefit from the translations.  However, the downside is that now all of your plugins will also need to know about the database (in some way).  That adds a more direct coupling that I prefer to avoid when using third party plugins.

If you use the resource files, you gain more flexibility but lose the ability to reuse the same text (which feels like you are violating DRY).

Personally, I would go down the resource file route for your localization.  It provides you the simplest way to get everyone working without major dependancies.  However, if you can figure out a way to have the plugins call the central application for their localization text, the central database would be a better option (again, in my mind).

Here are a couple links that might help you out as well:

[Is there a best-practice approach for internationalization of an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588127/is-there-a-best-practice-approach-for-internationalization-of-an-application)

http://www.businessandprocess.com/2010/11/why-application-localization-should-start-in-the-design-stage/

http://expatsoftware.com/articles/2010/03/why-internationalization-is-hopelessly.html